# Getting form field values in php and then disabling it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i am using form in my page like this

```
<form method='post' action='' class='myform'>    
   <input type='text' name='name'>
   <input type='text' name='email'>
   <input  class='btn' type='submit' name='submit' >
</form>
```

what i want i will get the values of form and then disable all  its fields , now this is my code to disable all fields when form is submitted

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(event) {
var currentForm = $(this).closest('form');
currentForm.find('input').prop('disabled', true); 
});
```

and before this i'm trying to get values from `$_POST` like this

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){                
       $name= $_POST["name"]; 
       $email= $_POST["email"];
}
```

but problem is that as i press submit button fields get disabled and i dont get any posted  values , how do i get values first and then disable fields ?

Comment: if you submit the form do you redirect it back to the form if not then there is not use of disabling the fields

Comment: change to readonly instead of disabled

Comment: set your posted values in input value will solve the problem

Comment: @rahul can  you please explain  ?

Comment: whenever you submit your form without ajax,your page will be reloaded. So basically if you clicked on submit button, values will be send to server and browser will reload the page and Jquery (Client side scripting language will refresh and your fields will again be enabled again). 

you have two options, First Change your fields to read only but fields will be activated when your form is successfully submitted and page is reloaded. Second  you have to use php to disable your form fields if you want to keep them disabled when page is loaded after the successful submission of form.

Comment: @Sikander solved your problem?

Comment: no , when i submit  data is recieved but form fields dont get disabled so searching  for  readonly  details

Comment: i have edited my code have you tried that ?

Answer (score 2):

**Your mistake** - You are disabling the input field by

```
currentForm.find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

So when you submit the form, the field will be in disabled state and will not be posted.

**Solution** - please change the line to

`currentForm.find('input').prop('readonly', true);`

Comment: This guy gets it! ;-) frirst solid answer to the question.

Comment: but he want to disabled the inputs :)

Comment: Disabled in the sense, user should not be able to edit the values in the field after submitting. Setting the "readonly" property achieves that.

Answer (score 0):

look this example or try with it....

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{                
   $name= $_POST["name"]; 
   $email= $_POST["email"];
}
?>
<form method='post' action='' class='myform'>
<?php
if($name != '' && $email != '')
{
?>
   <input type='hidden' name='name'  value="<?php echo $name?>">
   <input type='hidden' name='email'  value="<?php echo $email?>">  
<?php
}
?>    
<input type='text' name="<?php echo ($name != ''?'hidden_name':'name')?>"   <?php echo ($name != ''?'disabled':'')?> value="<?php echo $name?>">
   <input type='text' name='<?php echo ($email != ''?'hidden_email':'email')?>' <?php echo ($email != ''?'disabled':'')?> value="<?php echo $email?>">
   <input  class='btn' type='submit' name='submit' >
</form>
```

Comment: so using this how do i catch these values in  $_post array ?

Comment: Disabled inputs won't be submitted. Not only will this not work, it will generate undefined variable warnings.

Comment: add hidden input for them

Comment: wait i ll give you solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for that like this:

```
$('.btn').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "your page url here",
        type: 'POST',
        async:false,
        success: function(response) {           
            $('input').prop('disabled', true); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't pass submit parameter to formdata, that's why you can't get it.
try this

`<?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ echo $_POST['name'] }?>`

Comment: Not my downvote, but if you add no path in the action attribute, it will just send to it self.